# What is the best way to cache data in an ASP.Net application to prevent multiple queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a logic in my ASP.NET application which needs to check before some key operations if the user is eligible to execute this operation.

I dont want to check on each page_load on each page. What is the best way to do this for example one time within the application and provide the result also other pages without each time checking?

Comment: Side note: if operations are really important then checking permission every time is likely the best solution from correctness/security point of view (preferably as part of the operation itself to avoid temptation to cache access rights)... Otherwise session state as suggested by Dan Def is fine.

Comment: Side note 2: "the best way" is generally sign of low quality question as there rarely is universal criteria for why one approach would be "better" than another.

Answer (score 1):

If the permission is specific to the user you should store eligibility in [Session State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) and check that each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can look also into `Token based authentication`. When the user logs into your application you will give him a `token` which will be stored and sent with every request by the client to your server.

I'm pretty sure that the `token` can also contain specific permissions per user. For example: some of your users may be allowed to execute one of your operations while some may not.